# Flutter Web - FireBase Storage - Image doesn't store as image file

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

[Uploading Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmnv2.png%5D%5B1%5D)

When I try to upload images, they store there as file so download url gives error for images.

[Firebase Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fQiu.png)
[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTZMG.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content such as error messages. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a CORS related issue, see [this official page](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web-images#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors) for solutions.

Not sure what impact this will have (if any), but I'm also noting you haven't [specified the MIME type](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/upload-files#add-file-metadata) and the MIME type of the file is `application/octet-stream`, consider specifying the correct MIME type for the file i.e. `image/jpeg` for JPEG.